# Windows 8 UPNP much slower than accessing shared folder

Tags: windows-8, performance, dlna, upnp

Sharing from Windows Media Player in Windows 8 RTM (fresh install last week) to allow access to my libraries to other devices via dlna/upnp seems to give stuttering output and appears to be experiencing some kind of choke, but accessing the same files over a file share directly is fine.

The devices I'm trying to view from are Windows 7 machines (ultimate and home premium) and a [Sumvision MKV1](http://sumvision.com/productinfo/cyclonemkv/cyclonemkv.asp) linux box.  All 3 Windows machines are on a wired connection though the sumvision box is wireless. Unfortunately the sumvision box can't get to the share.  The same machine was running the Community Preview before and was not exhibiting problems serving up content.

Can someone explain why this is happening or point me in the direction of tools I can use to troubleshoot it?